# Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as array. FatalErrorException

Tags: arrays, laravel, class, object

I've encountered this problem (

> Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as array

) while doing an e-commerce site using Laravel, I tried to get the name of the purchased products. My controller function is this

> $orders=Auth::user()->orders;
>
> $orders->transform(function($orders, $key)   {
>     $orders->cart=unserialize($orders->cart);
>
> return $orders;
>   });
>
> return view('shop.profile', ['orders'=>$orders]);

The problem in the view code is this exact line `{{$item['item']['name']}}`, without it, i can see the quantity puchased, the price and anything else.

I've done everything I knew and found on the internet, but didn't find any solution

Comment: Can you show the code in the view as well? It is a little unclear what data you are interested in, but i think the view-code would help.

Comment: `<h2 align="center">My orders</h2> <br/>
@foreach($orders as $order)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="list-group">
      @foreach($order->cart->items as $item)
      <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="badge">{{$item['price']}} lei</span>
       {{$item['item']['name']}} | {{$item['qty']}}
        </li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer"><strong>Total Price: {{$order->cart->totalPrice}} lei </strong></div>
</div>
@endforeach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your information, i would assume you could use a solution like this:

```
<h2 align="center">My orders</h2> <br/>
@foreach($orders as $order)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach($order->cart->items as $item)
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <span class="badge">{{$item->price}} lei</span> 
                        {{$item->item->name }} | {{$item->qty }} 
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer"><strong>Total Price: {{$order->cart->totalPrice}} lei </strong></div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Normally, you do not talk to the $items like an array, but like an object. I believe this should do the trick, please let me know if it worked :)

Comment: I tried it already. And i get another error (trying to get property of a non-object)

Comment: Could you specify in more detail what the exact line is causing the issue? I could imagine {{$item->item->name }} needing to be {{$item->->name }}, could this be correct?

Comment: Somehow it works now with the initial code, even if i worked on other view pages today. Thank you very much for your help anyway. I just think laravel is very weird. One day it works, then the other day it fails. And viceversa

Comment: No worries. Maybe you can vote up and mark as answered, thank you in advance ;)